# How do I render a view to a variable with Hapi?

Tags: view, hapi.js

Is there a way to render a view to a variable? I want to change this.

```js
var events = {
  lastIndex: 32,
  payload = [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Hello world!"
      conyent: "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: "Hello world!"
      conyent: "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    ...
    {
      id: 32,
      title: "Hello world!"
      conyent: "Lorem ipsum"
    }
  ]
};

return reply.view('event/list', {
  events: events.payload
});
```

To this:

```js
return {
  events.lastIndex: 32,
  view: toView('event/list',events.payload)
}
```

I'm using Hapi v8 and Jade as render engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`server.render()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#serverrendertemplate-context-options-callback). Example from the documentation:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: 80 });
server.views({
    engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
    path: __dirname + '/templates'
});

var context = {
    title: 'Views Example',
    message: 'Hello, World'
};

server.render('hello', context, function (err, rendered, config) {

    console.log(rendered);
});
```